# More precise time for python-bunyan logger?

Tags: python, logging, bunyan

I've been using `bunyan` logger for `nodejs`, so when I had to program in `python` again I went out and found a compatible logger for `python`.

https://github.com/Sagacify/logger-python

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunyan/0.1.2

The problem is, this formatter only log time to second but I need at least millisecond precision. What would be the easiest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milliseconds would be a bit of a hack, but you can add microseconds really easily.

Here:

https://github.com/Sagacify/logger-python/blob/master/bunyan/formatter.py#L106

You would need to replace "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" by "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ"

Notice the added %f . 
(I'm actually the maintainer of saga-logger and we should be doing this as well but I haven't had the time to do it as of now.)

Comment: Thank you ! Yea I ended up using a hack by customizing the emit function of my log handler , specifically catered for my use case so I don't consider it elegant but it was easier for me because I didn't want to modify the Bunyan package . Thank you for the answer tho !